# Datepicker inside modal dialog not working

Tags: javascript, jquery

This question was asked many times and had different answers, i tried all solution suggested (using the z-index property ...) but still not working.
In a page (not a popup) the code works fine.
This is my code :

**Modal popup :**

```
<button class="btn btn-azure" id="bootbox-operation">Add operation</button>

<div id="newOperationModal" style="display: none;">
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-6 col-sm-6 col-xs-12">
        <div class="form-group">
            <div class="input-group">
                <input class="form-control datepicker" type="text" data-date-format="dd-mm-yyyy">
                <span class="input-group-addon">
                    <i class="fa fa-calendar"></i>
                </span>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
```

**Jquery script:**

```
   $(function () {
        $("#bootbox-operation").on('click',
            function () {                   
                bootbox.dialog({
                    message: $("#newOperationModal").html(),                       
                    title: "Nouvelle opération : Chargement",
                    className: "modal-success",
                    buttons: {
                        success: {
                            label: "Enregistrer",
                            className: "btn-blue",
                            callback: function () { }
                        },
                        "Annuler": {
                            className: "btn-default",
                            callback: function () { }
                        }
                    }
                });
                $(function () { 
                    console.log("test");
                    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
                });  
            });

    });

    //--Bootstrap Date Picker--
    //$(function () { // will trigger when the document is ready
    //    $(".datepicker").datepicker();
    //});
```

Comment: where is the script       **$("#bootbox-operation").on('click',** written.. ??

Comment: the scripte of $("#bootbox-operation").on('click' is a file that comes from the template..

Comment: call the template at the bootom of modal  <script src="//template..> & if not stil not working physically add the .on(click script below the modal

Comment: I tried both suggestions and still not working!, i inspect the html code and i see that the code of the modal is generated when i click the button to display the popup

Comment: Thanks @RohitasBehera, still the same probleme, can't get calendar in the input inside modal!

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/157128/discussion-between-omar-amezoug-and-rohitas-behera).

Comment: did **shown.bs.modall** worked ??

Comment: let's continu in chat pls, yes i do tried it, but seems that i need to change this name..

Answer (score 0):

because you are calling the date picker outside...call it on modal completion call back i.e. `.on('shown.bs.modal'`

```
  $(function () {

       var box=  bootbox.dialog({
                    message: $("#newOperationModal").html(),                       
                    title: "Nouvelle opération : Chargement",
                    className: "modal-success",
                    buttons: {
                        success: {
                            label: "Enregistrer",
                            className: "btn-blue",
                            callback: function () { }
                        },
                        "Annuler": {
                            className: "btn-default",
                            callback: function () { }
                        }
                    }
                });

                box.on("shown.bs.modal", function() {
                     $(".datepicker").datepicker();
                 });

           });
```